# Double relationship between two tables

Tags: mysql, model, diagram

I am trying to model a database diagram and found myself stucked in one question.
I have a User (id, name, email, ...) table and Meetings (id, id_from, id_to, return). I want to have a 1:1(not sure if its right) relationship from Meetings (id_from AND id_to) refering User (id). Should i create two Foreign Keys (FK_MEETINGS_ID_FROM and FK_MEETINGS_ID_TO) linking they to User (id) ? And in MySQL Workbench, how would it looks like on Diagram?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427501/one-to-one-relationship-in-mysql ?

Comment: Not, because i want a help with the diagram and modeling part, not the database or code itself